# While in while cycle, wrong result

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I need a script that displays the following: Country > Region's (a lot) > city on this regions (a lot too). Try, but cant :( Help

```
$get_all = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."_shop_cities WHERE type='0'");   # Берем страны
    while($row = $db->get_row($get_all)){
        $get_regions = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."_shop_cities WHERE god='$row[id]' AND type='1'"); # Регионы
        while($row2 = $db->get_row($get_regions)){
            $get_cities = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."_shop_cities WHERE god='$row2[id]' AND type='2'"); # города
            while($row3 = $db->get_row($get_cities)){
                $tpl->load_template("eshop/citylist.tpl");
                $tpl->set("{city_name}", "<li>".$row3["name_ru"]."</li>");
                $tpl->compile("cities");
                $tpl->clear();
            }
            $tpl->load_template("eshop/regionslist.tpl");
            $tpl->set("{region_name}", $row2["name_ru"]);
                $tpl->set("{cities}", $tpl->result["cities"]);
            $tpl->compile("regions");
            $tpl->clear();
        }
        $tpl->load_template("eshop/countrylist.tpl");
        $tpl->set("{name_country}", $row["name_ru"]);
        $tpl->set("{regions}", $tpl->result["regions"]);
        $tpl->compile("citylist");
        $tpl->clear();
    }
```

Comment: what about to use one mysql query with "join" ?

Comment: can you give me example, pls

Comment: try this $get_all = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."_shop_cities ORDER BY god"); the result should be 0 - страна, 1 - регион, 2 - город with just one query instead of 3, what problems/errors do you get?

Comment: if it possible can you please upload table, so I can try to write you a query

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dle_shop_cities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` text NOT NULL,
  `name_ru` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `name_en` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `name_kz` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `god` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

Comment: I want print: Country > region > cities and again country > region > many cities. And im use templater, necessarily use while for cycle printing

Comment: if this can help you, prewiew: http://twl.smartdrop.kz/?do=geolocation click on link where town not found

Comment: Try this query "SELECT a.name_ru as Country, b.name_ru AS Region, c.name_ru AS City FROM dle_shop_cities AS a JOIN dle_shop_cities AS b ON a.id = b.god AND b.type = 1 JOIN dle_shop_cities AS c ON b.id = c.god AND c.type = 2"

Comment: im use answer for question) check pls

Answer (score 0):

Im try do this:

```
$get_all = $db->query("SELECT a.name_ru as Country, b.name_ru AS Region, c.name_ru AS City FROM dle_shop_cities AS a JOIN dle_shop_cities AS b ON a.id = b.god AND b.type = 1 JOIN dle_shop_cities AS c ON b.id = c.god AND c.type = 2");   # Берем страны
while($row = $db->get_row($get_all)){

            $tpl->load_template("eshop/citylist.tpl");
            $tpl->set("{city_name}", "<li>".$row["City"]."</li>");
            $tpl->compile("cities");
            $tpl->clear();

        $tpl->load_template("eshop/regionslist.tpl");
        $tpl->set("{region_name}", $row[Region]);
            $tpl->set("{cities}", $tpl->result["cities"]);
        $tpl->compile("regions");
        $tpl->clear();

    $tpl->load_template("eshop/countrylist.tpl");
    $tpl->set("{name_country}", $row["Country"]);
    $tpl->set("{regions}", $tpl->result["regions"]);
    $tpl->compile("citylist");
    $tpl->clear();
}
```

Not successful, 
Россия
Новосибирская область
Омск
**Россия**
*Новосибирская область*
Омск
*Новосибирская область*
Омск
Новосибирск
**Россия**
*Новосибирская область*
Омск
*Новосибирская область*
Омск
Новосибирск
*Московская область*
Омск
Новосибирск
Москва
Help again pls

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$country = $region = '';
$get_all = $db->query("SELECT a.name_ru as Country, b.name_ru AS Region, c.name_ru AS City FROM dle_shop_cities AS a JOIN dle_shop_cities AS b ON a.id = b.god AND b.type = 1 JOIN dle_shop_cities AS c ON b.id = c.god AND c.type = 2 ORDER BY a.name_ru, b.name_ru, c.name_ru");   # Берем страны
while($row = $db->get_row($get_all)) {
  if($country != $row['Country']) {
    $tpl->load_template("eshop/countrylist.tpl");
    $tpl->set("{name_country}", $row["Country"]);
    $tpl->compile("citylist");
    $tpl->clear();
    $country = $row['Country'];
  }
  if($region != $row['Region']) {
    $tpl->load_template("eshop/regionslist.tpl");
    $tpl->set("{region_name}", $row[Region]);
    $tpl->compile("regions");
    $tpl->clear();
    $region = $row['Region'];
  }
  $tpl->load_template("eshop/citylist.tpl");
  $tpl->set("{city_name}", "<li>".$row["City"]."</li>");
  $tpl->compile("cities");
  $tpl->clear();
}
```